# Blazor webassembly, check if Policy exists

Tags: authorization, httpclient, blazor, synchronous, policy

In my blazor webassembly project i am trying to load poilicies from webapi, so that admin can set policies(permissions) for each role.
The problem is that the Authorization policy validation on the first page is done even before getting the response from httpclient request as it is async call, and i get an error the policy does not exists.
Is there any way that i can execute httpclient request synchronously OR check if the policy exists and wait till policy initialization is complete.

**JSON Object:**

```
[
 {"policy": "Administration","roles": ["admin"]},
 {"policy": "FinanceTransaction","roles": ["admin,accountant"]},
 .....
]
```

**Policy Initialization:**

```
   public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

            var baseAddress = builder.Configuration["apiUrl"];

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Anonymous", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress));

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Protected", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress));

            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("Protected"));


        builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(async options =>
            {
                var httpClientFactory = builder.Build().Services.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
                var http = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Anonymous");

                var tasks = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<PolicyRoles>>($"AppPolicy");
                foreach (var task in tasks)
                {
                    AppLoadStatus.PolicyLoaded = true;
                    OnPolicyLoaded.Invoke();
                    if (task.Roles.Any())
                        options.AddPolicy(task.Policy, policy => { policy.RequireRole(task.Roles); });
                }
            });

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
    }
```

**Razor Page:**

```
@page "/Items/"

@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "FinanceTransaction")]

<div class="col col-lg-9">
    @if (items == null)
      {
         <LoadingSpinner LoadFailed="@loadFailed" />
      }
    else
      {
         .....
     .....
 
      }
<div>
```

If i try to load the above page directly i get the error:
**crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: The AuthorizationPolicy named: 'FinanceTransaction' was not found**

But if i wait for policy initialization and navigate to other pages everything would work fine.

Can any one help me to resolve the issue. Or is there any other better approach for this

**app.razor:**

```
@if (!AppLoadStatus.PolicyLoaded)
{
    <LoadingSpinner />
}
else
{
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            <RedirectToLogin />
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <AccessDenied />
                        }
                    </NotAuthorized>
                </AuthorizeRouteView>
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <RedirectToHome />
                </LayoutView>
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
    </CascadingAuthenticationState>
}
@code{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ServiceExtensions.OnPolicyLoaded += () => { StateHasChanged(); };
    }
}
```

Comment: Id you set a breakpoint in the serrvicebuilder to see if the policies are actually loaded correctly?

Comment: The policy is loaded correctly. If i login, the index page is loaded first and works fine, because it is decorated with only authorize attribute. Now if i navigate from here to any page decorated with policies it also works fine. The problem is when anybody directly loads any url decorated with policy(like copy paste url to new tab) . In this case if the token stored in the local storage is not expired it will directly load the page and get the error 'policy not found' because the page gets loaded even before initializing the policy after async httpclient request

Comment: What about using the ```App.razor``` and showing your ```<LoadingSpinner >``` as long as your ```AppLoadStatus.PolicyLoaded = false```; It might slow down the loading time of pages that don't need authorization but should be a good first solution. A different approach would be to tweak the router logic a bit. If you are interested, I could create a quick example.

Comment: I had already tried that, but ClientConstants.PolicyLoaded value doesn't change. 
PolicyLoaded never gets notified and is always false.

Please find the code updated Above

Comment: Is there any different approach to achieve the same. Can anyone help.